# Reading from list of list

Tags: vb.net, list, vb.net-2010, nested-lists

I've been figuring out how to do the equivalent of multi-dimensional arrays using lists of lists in VB.Net. 
I need to setup a 3 dimensional list of list of list of string, fill it and then read it out. I've been successful in creating and filling the nested lists but I'm not getting the right output when I read it. 
I know it's correctly filled because if I read any one item, e.g.:

```
  listTest (1)(4)(2)
```

always gives me the correct result, in this case the second string in listInnerTwo  of the 4th set of lists in listInnerOne of the 1st set in List Test.

However when I try to read it with a nest of For Next Loops I only get a repetition of the string in the innermost list.
Here's my output code, it runs but doesn't give the right results (NL is new line):

```
For Each q As List(Of List(Of String)) In listTest
        For Each l As List(Of String) In listInnerOne
            For Each s As String In listInnerTwo
              myForm.TextBox.Text = myForm.TextBox.Text & s & NL
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 For Each q As List(Of List(Of String)) In listTest
     For Each l As List(Of String) In q
         For Each s As String In l
          myForm.TextBox.Text = myForm.TextBox.Text & s & NL
        Next
    Next
 Next
```

Comment: That did it.Thanks